# Get only the last rows after sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql

An example to my problem
    I have this table

```
ID | colA | ColB | Result
1  | 10   | 24   | 1       <- There is a newer row with the same colA and colB ( id=4)
2  | 12   | 24   | 0
3  | 95   | 22   | 0       <- There is a newer row with the same colA and colB ( id=6)
4  | 10   | 24   | 1
5  | 10   | 22   | 1
6  | 95   | 22   | 0
```

I wanna get only that rows with bigger IDs with the same colA and colB.after the request I should get this.

```
ID | colA | ColB | Result
2  | 12   | 24   | 0
4  | 10   | 24   | 1
5  | 10   | 22   | 1
6  | 95   | 22   | 0
```

I want a query that does this job. I'm thinking about triggers but a sql request should be better.

Comment: `... from tab t where not exists (select 1 from tab x where x.colA = t.colA AND x.colB=t.colB and x.id > t.id);`

Answer (score 3):

Use a CTE with a row_number()

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by ColA, ColB order by id desc) rn
from MyTable t1
)
select *
from CTE
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
    colA,
    colB,
    max(ID)

FROM
    TableA

 GROUP BY
    colA,
    colB
)

SELECT A.*
FROM
    TableA A
    JOIN cte C
        on C.ID = A.ID
```